# How to limit memory allocated by Java in CentOS 6?

Tags: java, memory, centos, cluster-computing

I have a Java application which uses 10 threads. Each thread opens a Matlab session by using the Java Matlabcontrol library. I'm running the application on a cluster running CentOS 6.

The used physical memory (Max Memory) for the whole application is around 5GB (as expected) but the reserved physical memory (Max Swap) is around 80GB which is too high. Here a short description from the cluster wiki:

> A note on terminology: in LSF the Max Swap is the memory allocated by
>   an application and the Max Memory is the memory physically used (i.e.,
>   it is actually written to). As such, Max Swap > Max Memory. In most
>   applications Max Swap is about 10–20% higher than Max Memory

I think the problem is Java (or perhaps a mix between Java and Matlab). Java tends to allocate about 50% of the physically available memory on a compute node by default. A java process assumes that it can use the entire resources available on the system that it is running on. That is also the reason why it starts several hundred threads (although my application only uses 11 threads). It sees 24 cores and lots of memory even though the batch system reserves only 11 core for the job.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Edit: I've just found the following line in the Matlabcontrol documentation:

> When running outside MATLAB, the proxy makes use of multiple
>   internally managed threads. When the proxy becomes disconnected from
>   MATLAB it notifies its disconnection listeners and then terminates all
>   threads it was using internally. A proxy may disconnect from MATLAB
>   without exiting MATLAB by calling disconnect().

This explains why there are a lot of threads created but it does not explain the high amount of reserved memory.

Edit2: Setting `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4` environment variable brought the amount of reserved memory down to 30GB. What value of MALLOC_ARENA_MAX should I choose and are they other tuning possibilities?

Comment: Java certainly doesn't start several hundred threads by default, at least not the implementations I've come across. There has to be something else going on there, probably in MatlabControl.

Comment: @biziclop Please see my update

Comment: Java starts with 25% of main memory by default, and 1 thread for local CPU for garbage collection.  You can change these defaults. You can also share one JVM for all your sessions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Please see my update regarding MALLOC_ARENA_MAX. If Java starts with 25% of main memory, this is really bad because the cluster has a lot of memory but I only use part of it of course. How can I limit this?

Comment: @machinery on the command line you would set `-Xmx1g` for example. I am not sure you you pass these options to your library.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks but setting the -Xmx flag does not help reducing the reserved memory. If I set -Xmx1g Max Swap is still 30GB.

Comment: @machinery how are you measuring the max swap?

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is measured by the cluster. When the job finished, the cluster shows a resource summary.

Comment: Without knowing what that means, it hard to know what to tune, unless this is saying your JVM swaps up to 30 GB while running.  Are you sure the option took effect and was passed correctly?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have passed the option correctly but I cannot see if it took effect. Max Swap is the memory allocated by the application, I cannot say more.

Comment: @machinery if you changed the maximum heap from the default, to just 1 GB and it had no effect on this number, I wouldn't take much notice of it until you know what it is.